# Encoding jump targets - Computer Systems A programmer's perspective

Tags: elf, disassembly

I'm reading through the part about how jump instructions are encoded and I am confused about the highlighted line of text: [image: See text here].

How is `0xf3 = decimal -13`? Is this an error? I tried checking the errata but nothing there either.

[image: here's the assembly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an error. "Single-byte, [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)" is the important part here.
So:

- 0xf3 in base 10 is (15 * 16) + (3 * 1) = 240 + 3 = 243
- 243 in binary is 11110011
- Using two's complement form to get the "actual" number in base 10:

11110011

= -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 0 * 8 + 0 * 4 + 2 + 1

= -128 + 64 + 32 + 16 + 2 + 1

= -13

Comment: Thank you! that explains it all :)